# Hide button based on reference from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to hide some buttons based on whether the user is an admin. I have added this in the database to show true or false. I have created an if statement so that when oncreate starts if the users admin is false the buttons should be hidden but this is not what is happening

The buttons are showing as normal

// this is the code i have in the on create

```
        databaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot venueSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = venueSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if(user.getAdminUser() == true)
                                    {
                    buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

//This is the entire oncreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        buttonAddBeverages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddBeverages);
        buttonAddProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddProducts);
        databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        //initializing firebase authentication object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //if the user is not logged in
        //that means current user will return null
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //initializing views
        textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

        //displaying logged in user name
        textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());

        databaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot venueSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = venueSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    if(user.getAdminUser() == true)
                                        {
                        buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //logging out the user
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                //closing activity
                finish();
                //starting login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do this in reverse. First hide button, then if true show the button.

    buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);                  
    if(user.equals(true))
      buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Or you may put your code when activity start
or in xml  <Button ... android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: I tried a that there but i am getting the wrong person showing as logged in when i debug it. Dose not seem to be getting the value of the current user.

Comment: i updated my code and added my entire oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonAddProducts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
buttonAddBeverages.setVisibility(View.INVICIBLE);
```

in your `xml` file use button as `invicible` first and if users is and admin try to use visible that will work

Comment: I think my problem is in the on create, when i debug it the code loops through every user in the table and if any are true it sets the buttons to visible. I just need to get just the current logged in users adminUser detail from the table. not sure how to go about it tho